# How to get ApplicationUser object for a given user

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

In my following action method I'm getting following `design time error` on line `var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "AdminRole");`. But if I use `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.SelectedUserName` to get a user then the above line does not give design time error, however; as expected, it gives `run time validation error` as: `User someUSerName already exist`. I understand the run time error is due to the fact that I'm adding a role to an existing user but passing a new instance of it. **Question**: How can I get an existing user as an ApplicationUser object so I can pass it to `AddToRoleAsync(....)` below? I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1.1, Individual User Accounts mode, VS2017.

**Error**:

```
Cannot convert from  Task<MyProj.Model.ApplicationUser> to MyProj.Model.ApplicationUser
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToRole(RoleRelatedViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.SelectedUserName); //cannot be used in AddToRoleAsync(user,"AdminRole") since FindByNameAsync returns Task<ApplicationUser>
        //var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.SelectedUserName };
        var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "AdminRole");
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.SelectedUserName);`

it seems like AddToRoleAsync expects ApplicationUser as first parameter, but you giving Task
So if you use **await** before FindByNameAsync call your *user* variable will be ApplicationUser.

Comment: Your solution worked. You actually explained to me true usage of `await` (thank you). There is a typo in your suggested solution. You probably missed  `FindByNameAsync` in `await _userManager.c(model.SelectedUserName);`. For benefit of other readers, could you please edit your solution - and I will mark it as an `Answer`